# How to center DIV while hidding it's scroll bar?

Tags: css, layout, overflow

I am trying to center the content of a DIV element, which has it's scroll bar hidden behind a parent. Looks something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zeyar/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content">
            This should be centered! This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!This should be centered!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 300px; /* unknown width - 100%* - browser size */
  height: 200px; /* unknown width - 100%* - broser size */
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #dedede;
}
.child {
  width: 120%; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #000;
}
.content {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
```

I have tried all kinds of stuff, but nothing seems to work.

I'd like to have this done cross browser and if a user re-sizes the window it still works. My problem is that the **scroll-bar width in different browsers changes** and that the screen width also is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it that should work in all browsers.

Modify your CSS as follows:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.parent {
    height: 100%;    /* unknown width - 100%* - browser size */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #dedede;
}
.child {
    width: 120%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    background: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

Set `position: relative` on the `.child` block, and then use `position: absolute` on the `.content` block.

To get the centering to work, use `left: 45%` and then shift the `.content` to the left using `margin-left: -75px`.

The value of of 45% is based on a bit of trial and error.

**Limitations**

If you shrink the window width small enough, you will see that the left and right spacing around the `.content` is not quite symmetric (2-3 pixels off).

If the window is tall enough, the content will not reach to the bottom of the screen so it is not vertically centered.

**Browser Support & Safari Quirk**
I tried the solution with Safari in Windows, and the vertical scrolling does not work using the mouse scroll. However, the solution works in FF, IE, Chrome, Opera (latest versions).

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/q3bKz/

Comment: This is very nice, but it is still 2-3 pixels off. I had a version where I did something similar, but this is still browser scroll-bar width dependent. Thanks though! ;)

Comment: I tried doing a similar thing by setting .child width back to 100% and adding - padding: 0 17px; margin-left: -8px. (This gets me pretty darn close to center, but it isn't really centered and browser is still dependent)

Comment: You could get a precise centering if you are willing to use JavaScript/jQuery.  What you need to do is get the with of `.parent` and then set the `left` offset for `.content` as {half-width of .parent} minus {half-width of .content}  You then need to attach the Javascript function to a onload/onresize event.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your jsfiddle, I found the reason why it wasn't centering. You had set your width to 120%, if you change it to 100% it centers the child div. However while doing this, it does bring back the scroll bar. I'm working on that though.

**update**

I know you've already accepted an answer but if you don't want to use javascript/jquery and just use normal css, then you could also try using this in the css

```
.content {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
    transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
}
```

Comment: The point of .child with 120% width is to hide the .scroll-bar underneath the .parent with 100%width and overflow:hidden.

Comment: @Teodors I know you accept an answer but I updated my answer so that the scroll-bar disappears and that the content centers in the middle.